# Apache mod-rewrite regex bug?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm trying to forward requests one folder up like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(contact)/(.+)$ $2
```

It's working fine but changing `contact` to `[a-z]+` will not function as expected:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.+)$ $2
```

This is a sample URL working with the first method and not working with second one:

```
http://localhost/bb/contact/company/img/group/3.png
Root is : http://localhost/bb/
```

Comment: You could provide some sample data where this is failing for you? Right off the bat I can't claim there's anything wrong with your regular expression.

Comment: In that case, I can't see anything wrong with your regular expression: http://regex101.com/r/eI6wI6

Answer (score 0):

If `Root is : http://localhost/bb/` then you will need `RewriteBase` as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bb/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.+)$ $2 [L,NC]
```

This will internally forward `http://localhost/bb/contact/company/img/group/3.png` to `http://localhost/bb/company/img/group/3.png`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: The problem is not solved using `RewriteBase`. the problem is somehow related to regex because replacing `[a-z]+` with `contact` and also `.......` works as expected

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your last comment. Are you still seeing this problem?

Comment: Yes. It's not working with the new code. As I said, replacing regex with exact string solves the problem. It seems a bug in regex engine.

Comment: If regex engine can match `.+` then it should work for `[a-z]+` also, problem is something else.